# Auto fill form with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

**Site in question**

https://form.gov.sg/#!/5e3790e4d3eeea0011bd2d29

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('5e353dd16509040011d0333a').value="S1234567C"
document.getElementById('5e3541216509040011d0338b').value="36.8"
document.getElementById('5e353ed27146b10011d4b660').value = "On-Duty"
document.getElementById('5e3542a35cff5300119a8ec6').value = "NUH"

completion();
```

the above code works on the first 2 elements but does not autofill the fields with drop down boxes
I have tried defaultValue as well and selectedIndex but can't get it to work

May I have some help please!

Comment: *I have tried defaultValue as well and selectedIndex* - doesn't look like you've tried those things - perhaps your attempt to do so is wrong. are these "dropdown boxes" a `<select>` element? or something else? (not going to some random link - you need to show the part of the HTML you're dealing with)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This website uses Angular and [ng-selectize package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-selectize), so you should set the value according to the documentation of that package.

Your code doesn't work, because there are elements in DOM serving as enhancement for that input (selecting feature). The elements under your third and fourth IDs are actually `<div>`, not `<input>`. You can change the value of these inputs directly like that:

```js
document.getElementById('5e353ed27146b10011d4b660').querySelector('.ui-select-search').value = 'On-Duty'
```

But better idea would be to do that Angular-friendly way, unless you need it for a quick and dirty job.

Comment: thanks for the quick fix! works great. 

I tried to submit form using document.getElementById('forms.myForm').submit(); but it isn't working, do you have a fix for this? thank you

Comment: It should be `document.forms['forms.myForm'].submit()`.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using a custom select (plugin or some javascript library), you should after setting the value just trigger change event for each of those drop downs.

Answer (score 0):

as said, it's an angular app. so the component is not a native select box. you could click on the element to open it and then click on the option which is only visible when the select box is opened.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('selectize-input')[0].click()
setTimeout(()=> {document.querySelector('div.ui-select-choices-row.ng-scope.active > div').click()}, 1000)
```

you can generalize it for other questions.