# How to get autofiiled input value?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get autofiiled input value, so i can insert it back in, through `document.getElementById.value` on page load. But i cant get the autofilled value ,its Empty.
How do i get it?

```
<input tabindex="1" id="username" placeholder="${msg("username")}"
                                  name="username"
                                   type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
```

On logging it the first time

```
console.log(document.getElementById('username').value);
```

I get this

```
<input tabindex="1" id="username" placeholder="User ID" class="form-control" name="username" value="" type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

Value is Empty

The problem is when i write `document.getElementById("username").value` in console, it gives me autofilled value, But isnt working when i run it in code, it shows me empty. I have kept the script at the end of the page

Thank You!

Comment: What did you try so far? And what does the expression `(login.username!'')` means?

Comment: Is this HTML or some other framework? Please add relevant tags.

Comment: I removed it, it was ftl, it has no relation to this problem

Comment: the problem is when i write `document.getElementById("username").value` in console, it gives me autofilled value, But isnt working when i run it in code, it shows me empty

Answer (score 0):

Here's [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61419930/auto-fill-form-with-javascript)! help the understand to autofill form with js.
If you can't solve problem, we'll find another way to solve.

Comment: I think the answer is for angular app, but this is basic html